# PowerApps: Pull a specific record from a Sharepoint Lookup list to show additional fields using a Display Form

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I want to show additional columns from a Sharepoint Lookup list in a Display Form when looking at the detail record of a SharepointList.

I added a 2nd Display Form to a Canvas. I set the Datasource to the Sharepoint List. I added the additional fields in the lookup table. I set the Item to the lookup field of the selected record.

The Display Form remains empty.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the `DefaultMode` of the Form Control is set to `New`.